# How to change syntax-hihglightning for *sass.rb file in Aptana Studio?

Tags: aptana, syntax-highlighting, sass

I am using Aptana and on rails i have .sass files with .rb extension, for example screen.css.sass.rb .

How could i make Aptana to able to highlight .sass.rb extension as sass document?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is an issue with Eclipse that has not been resolved. You could add your vote in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=89859.